# Tcl Regex for variable filename

Tags: regex, file, variables, directory, tcl

Would like to make my Directorypath flexible to run a script in tcl. The path is always the same, only the end like "V1" is different. Maybe it works with a regular Expression (e.g. C:/Users/testuser/Desktop/TempTCL/*.dat)

```
set filename "C:/Users/testuser/Desktop/TempTCL/V1.dat"
```

Is it possible to scan all .dat files in a diretory and run one script with all possibilities?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `glob` command is what you need to use. It returns a list of filenames that you can iterate over with `foreach` (or anything else that you prefer; it's a plain old list). You can give a pattern, and the `-directory` option makes it all really easy. Here; take a look at this:

```
set dir "C:/Users/testuser/Desktop/TempTCL"
foreach filename [glob -directory $dir *.dat] {
    puts "I found a file called $filename"
}
```

Change the body for your processing code (with that convenient full filename in `$filename`) and the job's done.